# As for Wednesday we better meet / met before noon because

Tags: verbs

(UK English, native: German)
I need to make a proposal for an appointment in an E-mail.
So far I have suggested some possibilities for Monday and Tuesday and now I would like to offer one last proposal for a meeting on Wednesday.

> As for Wednesday we better *meet* / *met* before noon because...

Would this sentence be fine and would I need to write "meet" or "met"? Or how would you write this?

Comment: The formal is: we had better meet before noon. Since this is basically editing or correct text, I am putting it here since this question will probably be closed. But you still need it, right?

Comment: *Met* is past tense.

Comment: Or more naturally "We should meet before noon".

Comment: Note, you'll be understood without it, but in my opinion clarity would be helped by adding a comma after "Wednesday."

Answer (score 3):

"We better" is colloquial for "We had better".

**had** is not forming the past perfect there. **had better** = should, and thus the infinitive **meet** is required.